# Automatting the CarrierWave upload process for 600+ previous images in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have just finished setting up CarrierWave to allow image uploads and processing for new products.  All this has been done in development.

Everything is working good, however I have over 600 existing products that need to be run through the upload process so that I have the correct versions and urls.

I have urls to all these images so I am using the remote_image_url feature in CarrierWave.

I uploaded an old image url through the browser and it worked out fine.  The image was processed and it was given new urls for each version.  Using the update method all the other attributes did not change as expected.

To automate this process, I figured I could write some code in a seed file and just run all the products through a loop.

I have been testing one single product in the console, but running into problems.

A) Is this the right approach?
B) Does anyone have any insight into how to complete this task

Here is my current code that I thought would work in the console

```
Photo.find_by(id_num: 'bw51').update(
  "default_mat"=>"4",
  "remote_image_url"=>"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/luminoto-enlarged/1423.jpg?", 
  "image_cache"=>"", 
  "is_active"=>"false",  
  "title"=>"Chicago Harbor Lighthouse", 
  "description"=>"<p>Add desc</p>", 
  "category_ids"=>["", "79"], 
  "film_type"=>"digital",    
  "year_taken"=>"2015", 
  "format_id"=>"1", 
  "show_bw_conversion"=>"true" 
)
```

This process shouldn't depend on my actions in the controller so I left out that code.

Thanks

Comment: Look at selenium web driver. If you can do it successfully in a GUI browser you can automate the browsers behavior with this library. Its a bit slow but with only 600 items that's unimportant.

Comment: after formatting the code, I noticed that you're missing a parenthesis on the `remote_image_url`.

Comment: sorry..that was a type from pasting into stack overflow.  the parenthesis was there when i ran it in console.  its been updated on the page